# How to get alphabetical AND numbered bibliography + numbered internal citations

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, bibliographystyle

I need my references to be numbered in the text, but listed alphabetically in the bibliography. For example:

> Smith et al. (2) said XXX. Abraham et al. (1) said YYY.
>
> Bibiliography
>
> 1. Abraham et al.
> 2. Smith et al.

From [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425837/alphabetical-sorting-of-the-bibliography-using-natbib-and-unsrtnat), I tried the following:

```
% in preamble
\usepackage[round, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
...
% at the end
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{refs.bib}
```

but then the references are not numbered, and accordingly the internal citations use author-year format.

How I get something more like `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`, but numbered?